# How to filter out a specific word from group of words in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

Hallo all i am trying to figure out the issue i have tried but not got successful. Can anyone please help me out in this . I shall be grateful to you.
Task:
I have a drop down list in excel like

Sales/Acquisition Manager (AM)-------------------------------Alina (Alina@yahoo.com)

Acquisition Project Manager (APM)--------------------------Benny(Benny@yahoo.com)

Manufacturing ----------------------------------------------------Julia(Julia@yahoo.com)

Application ---------------------------------------------------------please select (drop down list so I can choose)

AE external sensor responsible-------------------------------please select (Drop down list so I can choose)

I have made a separate row (row 59 Col A) where I have combined these values from the above rows.

I have to make a macro to send 1 email to these multiple people. I have written a code for sending email but I am stuck at some point. I have written a code which replaces the word please
select with “ ”  whenever it finds in row 59 but unfortunately that code changes the line permanently which I don’t want.
What I want is that whenever it finds a word please select in a row it just ignores it and and also don’t change the format of cell. Means when I again change some new value by drop down list so it got changed. I shall be really grateful to you if you please help me out in this . Thanks a lot.please check the attached pics also.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x36s.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsAoQ.png)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim the_string As String

the_string = Sheets("Schedule_team").Range("A59")

the_string = Replace(the_string, "please select", " ")

Sheets("Schedule_team").Range("A59") = the_string

MsgBox (Sheets("Schedule_team").Range("A59"))


Dim i As Integer, Mail_Object, Email_Subject, o As Variant, lr As Long, x As      
Variant
Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

x = Cells (59, 1).Value
With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
'            .Subject = Range("B1").Value
.To = x
'            .Body = Range("B2").Value
'            .Send
.display 'disable display and enable send to send automatically
End With

MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", 64
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set Mail_Object = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put quotes around `the_string` inside the `Replace()`

```
the_string = Replace("the_string", "please select", " ")
```

should be:

```
the_string = Replace(the_string, "please select", " ")
```

Here's a slight refactoring of your code which removes the need for that variable:

```
Sub RemoveHypens()

    With Sheets("Home").Range("A59")

         .Value = Replace(.Value, "please select", " ")

    End with

End Sub
```

EDIT: based on your updated question -

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim the_string As String
    Dim i As Integer, Mail_Object, Email_Subject, o As Variant
    Dim lr As Long

    the_string = Sheets("Schedule_team").Range("A59").Value

    the_string = Replace(the_string, "please select", " ")

    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
        '.Subject = Range("B1").Value
        .To = the_string
        '.Body = Range("B2").Value
        '.Send
        .display 'disable display and enable send to send automatically
    End With

    MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", 64
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set Mail_Object = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your cooperation. It worked but I have an issue I want to just ignore this word please select whenever it comes in text but when I use the command Replace then it changes the values of cell permanently.
What I am doing is I have a drop down list through which I change the email address so what I need is to write a code that whenever please select comes in cell (59,1) it ignores it but does not changes the function of cell permanently.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're doing.  It would help to expand your question to list the exact steps you want to carry out, including an explanation of your "drop down approach" - I have no idea what you might mean by that.

Comment: Please have a look at the updated code and question and figures also. Now i have tried to explain what i want to do and what i am doing . I hope that it will work now . Thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry for delayed reply. Thanks a lot for ur help. This code works perfect. Great. Thanks once again..